# Connecting to Azure flexible postgres with user managed identity

Tags: postgresql, azure, quarkus, vert.x, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to connect to Postgres database using Azure managed identity with a sample code as below

```
 import io.vertx.pgclient.PgConnectOptions; 
 import io.vertx.pgclient.PgPool; 
 import io.vertx.sqlclient.PoolOptions;
 import com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredential; 
 import com.azure.identity.TokenRequestContext; 
 import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
 
 public class PgConnectWithManagedIdentity {
 
     private static final String DB_HOST = "db-host";
     private static final String DB_NAME = "db-name";
     private static final String DB_USER = "db-user";
     private static final int POOL_SIZE = 5;
     private static final long TOKEN_RENEWAL_INTERVAL = 15 * 60 * 1000; // 15 minutes in milliseconds
 
     public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
         PgPool pgPool = initPgPool();
         // Execute SQL queries
         // ......
         // Close the pgPool
         pgPool.close();
     }
 
     private static PgPool initPgPool() throws InterruptedException {
         DefaultAzureCredential credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
         PgConnectOptions connectOptions = new PgConnectOptions()
                 .setHost(DB_HOST)
                 .setDatabase(DB_NAME)
                 .setUser(DB_USER)
                 .setPassword(credential.getToken(new TokenRequestContext().addScopes("https://ossrdbms-aad.database.windows.net/.default")).block().getToken())
                 .setPort(5432);
         PoolOptions poolOptions = new PoolOptions().setMaxSize(POOL_SIZE);
         PgPool pgPool = PgPool.pool(connectOptions, poolOptions);
         scheduleTokenRenewal(pgPool, credential);
         return pgPool;
     }
 
     private static void scheduleTokenRenewal(PgPool pgPool, DefaultAzureCredential credential) {
         Runnable task = () -> {
             pgPool.close();
             PgConnectOptions connectOptions = new PgConnectOptions()
                     .setHost(DB_HOST)
                     .setDatabase(DB_NAME)
                     .setUser(DB_USER)
                     .setPassword(credential.getToken(new TokenRequestContext().addScopes("https://ossrdbms-aad.database.windows.net/.default")).block().getToken())
                     .setPort(5432);
             PoolOptions poolOptions = new PoolOptions().setMaxSize(POOL_SIZE);
             PgPool newPgPool = PgPool.pool(connectOptions, poolOptions);
             pgPool = newPgPool;
         };
         long initialDelay = TOKEN_RENEWAL_INTERVAL - System.currentTimeMillis() % TOKEN_RENEWAL_INTERVAL;
         pgPool.vertx().setPeriodic(initialDelay, TOKEN_RENEWAL_INTERVAL, task);
     } }
```

But the refresh code does not seem to behave properly. I am able to make the first connection but unable to get the refreshtoken (not error but unable to connect). Is there any step I am missing or any issue in the understanding of how the behavior should be.